# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FETCH

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2

I'm migrating an application, that uses DB2 database, from Spring(IBM Websphere) to Springboot(Embedded Tomcat).

The existing application, that uses hibernate **4.1.9.Final**, runs perfectly using this FETCH query :

```
@Query(
"SELECT ssss FROM SSSSPackageDiscountLoad ssss, SSSBasicLoad ttt WHERE ssss.schemeId = ttt.id AND ttt.code = :schemeCode AND "
+ "ssss.ruleCode = :ruleCode ORDER BY ssss.effDate DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY")
```

The migrated springboot(version **2.1.7.RELEASE**) app uses hibernate **5.3.10.Final**.

Starting the application gives me this issue :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: FETCH near line 1, column 255

Answer (score 0):

You could use the equivalent statement:

```
@Query(
"SELECT ssss FROM SSSSPackageDiscountLoad ssss, SSSBasicLoad ttt WHERE ssss.schemeId = ttt.id AND ttt.code = :schemeCode AND "
+ "ssss.ruleCode = :ruleCode ORDER BY ssss.effDate DESC LIMIT 1")
```

However, if you want to use the query as it is, then you would need to force the dialect as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273992/hibernate-5-change-not-to-use-fetch-first-rows-only).

In your case, this should work:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

From another post: [unexpected token: LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574674/unexpected-token-limit)

Basically your query should be native:

```
`@Query(
"SELECT ssss FROM SSSSPackageDiscountLoad ssss, SSSBasicLoad ttt WHERE ssss.schemeId = ttt.id AND ttt.code = :schemeCode AND "
+ "ssss.ruleCode = :ruleCode ORDER BY ssss.effDate DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY", nativeQuery = true)`
```

Notice the `nativeQuery` at the end.
By default, `nativeQuery` is false.